# How to sign macOS apps? Does it cost?

Tags: macos

I want to sign my macOS apps with my apple ID, but does it cost money to enroll in the apple developer program in order to sign my apps? Or Is it for free? How? I have tried searching this up but i'm just really confused right now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the footer  of https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/ you can read (written in dark grey on light grey ):

> The Apple Developer Program is 99 USD per membership year or in local currency where available.